# Output in 2 columns

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make this:

```
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ af86df6737cf43a6bf5ab0f822791450    0   S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ afd53ab9b77ffa1dd8ad365577bec497    0   S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ b024027f366a3c7e567b3fdd94b892f2    0   S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document
```

Look like this:

```
S036GDLv02 3
S040PDFv02 2
S043GUIv02 23
S046CONv02 1
```

I want to have it display each unique file, then have it output the count of that file type right next to it in two neat columns.

What I have so far is

```
cut -f 4 input.txt|sort| uniq | sed 2d;;
```

but that's only outputting the data like this:

```
S036GDLv02
S040PDFv02
S043GUIv02
S046CONv02
```

Comment: Where are the 3/2/23/1 in your output coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `uniq -c` instead of `uniq` and remove the `sed`.

Comment: thank you! Is it possible to get the number to display on the right side of the text?

Comment: You can do some simple post processing e.g. `cut -f 4 input.txt|sort| uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $1}'`

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '{c[$4]++} END{for (v in c) print v, c[v];}'
```

This counts the unique occurrences of the fourth column and then prints them out.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print $4,$5,$6}' test.txt | uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $1, $3, $4}'
```